# How can I refer another table to be a source for multiple likes within a case-when in BigQuery?

Tags: loops, google-bigquery

So I have a table listing all kind of url types (for example: Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc.)
I want to achieve result similar to from this one:

```
select
  url
  ,(case
    when url like '%facebook%' then 'Facebook'
    when url like '%instagram%' then 'Instagram'
    ....
  end) as type
```

However the problem is the list goes on with around 30-40 items, and I don't want to list them all manually.
Is there any way to achieve this?
I'm thinking about using loop but can't get it right.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using BigQuery with `dbt` you can achieve this with Jinja macros https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros/#jinja, otherwise try doing a LEFT join with Sergey's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe as an alternative you can use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract):

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT "https://www.facebook.com/qwe" AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT "http://abc.instagram.com/zxc"
)
SELECT
  url,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r"^https?:\/\/([^\/?]+)") AS type
FROM test_table
```

[image]

### EDIT:

Similar to Michel's brilliant suggestion you can create additional table with a list of domains and their search strings. But make sure that single url won't fall under several conditions otherwise such url will be duplicated in the output.

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT "https://www.facebook.com/qwe" AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT "http://abc.instagram.com/zxc"
),
social_networks AS (
  SELECT '%facebook%' as search_string, 'Facebook' AS type UNION ALL
  SELECT '%instagram%', 'Instagram'
)
SELECT
  url, social_networks.type
FROM test_table JOIN social_networks 
ON test_table.url LIKE social_networks.search_string
```

[image]

Comment: Almost it ! And then maintain a `social_networks` reference table that has all the (`type`, `label`) pairs and just JOIN the two tables on `type` key.